# Java delete first part of string (case-insensitive)

Tags: java

I searched and couldn't find the right code as I only saw case sensitive ones.

I am writing code that checks that the file name starts with "CMF-".
I have the code that if the name doesn't start with CMF- then it is added (this works).

However, I am having an issue with case-sensitivity. The first if statement is where I need help.

For example, when someone saves the name as cmf-something then I need to delete the cmf- and put CMF- in its place.
As another example, someone saves a file as Cmf-something it will also need to delete the Cmf- and put CMF- in its place.

```
    String name = document.getObjectName();

    String newName;

    String haystack = "CMF-";
    if(haystack.regionMatches(true, 0, name, 0, 4) && !name.startsWith(haystack))
    {
        //part to delete lowercase cmf and then add cmf
    }

    //Check the object name for CMF-
    if(!haystack.regionMatches(true, 0, name, 0, 4))
    {
        //System.out.println("Missing CMF- on name \nAdding CMF- to " + name);

        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("CMF-");
        newName = str.append(name).toString();

        document.setObjectName(newName);
    }
```

Comment: you mean if a file starts as `Cmf` or `cMf` or `cmf` etc you should delete it and add it but uppercase?

Comment: Why are you using a buffer why not just string concartination ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, just make it lowercase and check

```
if(newString.toLowerCase().starstWith("cmf")){
  newString = newString.substring(3);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the second parameter in substring. substring(3) returns the substring from index 3 to the end.

Comment: The names of the methods are `substring` and `startsWith`, not `subString` and `startWidth`.

Comment: @sbat thanks edit made :) I was clearly a little to faste to post sorry about that

Comment: THanks just got done testing. I just had to change subtring to parameter 4.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems overly complicated. Why not do something like:

```
String name = document.getObjectName();
//Check for names starting "CMF-", "cmf-", "Cmf-", etc.
if (name.substring(0,4).equalsIgnoreCase("CMF-")){
    name = "CMF-"+name.substring(4); //May even overwrite correct name.
} else {
    name = "CMF-" + name;
}
```

And you can also include some error checking for names that would be too short and cause out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: I wanted to do something like this but was told to use the append.

Comment: Your instructor sounds particular irritating in that case

Answer (score 1):

I like [Lars Nielsen solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789495/java-delete-first-part-of-string-case-insensitive/24789788#24789610) for it's simplicity, but if you would like to see how regular expression will look  in such case, here it is:

```
"Cmf-abc".matches("(?i)^cmf-.*"); // true
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/Z5B9cR).

Regular expression `(?i)^cmf-.*` works like this:

- `(?i)` enables case insensitive-matching (by default it is case-sensitive).
- `^cmf-` means that we want to have `cmf-` (or `Cmf-`, `CMF-`, ...) in the beggining of the string...
- `.*` - ...followed with whatever.